# operator precedence question between `<<` and `==`

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class point
{
public:
    int x, y;
    point(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a, y = b;
    }
    bool operator==(point &a)
    {
        if (a.x == x && a.y == y)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    point a(5, 7), b(5, 7);
    int t = a == b;
    cout<<t;  //it is working properly
    cout<< (a==b); // it also
    cout << a==b; //but it gives me compilation error
}
```

what is the reason...??
is there any fact of operator precedence...?? 
I don't know why it is giving compilation error...
as it is seen it looks fine

Comment: That's because of operator precedence. Basically it's like writing `(cout << a)==b;`

Comment: The issue, as you have mentioned, is operator order of precendence. << comes before ==. The compiler sees (cout << a) == b, even though you meant cout << (a==b)

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: Don't tag C when this is clearly a C++ question, they are different languages.

Comment: When in doubt, use parenthesis - there is no shame in this and I encourage it.

Comment: [cppreference's _Operator Precedence_ page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) makes for a good bookmark bar icon ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator.  So this:

```
cout << a==b;
```

Is parsed as this:

```
(cout << a ) == b;
```

This causes an error because there is no overload of `operator<<` for `cout` that takes `point` as an argument.

The explicit parenthesis in your first example is the proper way to handle this.